# take specific text out of a list and assign it as a string to a different variable

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm trying to extract the part in between the quotes and assign it as a string to a variable.

That is: "`/dasd/273627/aaa`".

How can I achieve this?

```
[u'/dasd/273627/aaa']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract it using `re library(regex)` in Python.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('u\'(.*)\'')
listA = [u'/dasd/273627/aaa']
m = pattern.match(listA[0])
m = m.group(1) // m will contain the string inside single quotes
```

Refer to [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) and [grouping](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping) for more info.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The part in between the quotes *is* the value of the item already, so given `l = [u'/dasd/273627/aaa']` all you need to do to assign the value of the list item to a variable `s` is to either:

```
s = l[0]
```

or:

```
s, = l
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `re.split`:

```
import re
str= [u'/dasd/273627/aaa']
newstr = re.split(r'/', str)
```

I hope I understood your question...